# Not able to load .ttf in React

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face

It throws DOM EXCEPTION

styles file

```
  import { fontUrls1 } from './Fonts/Amaranth-Bold.ttf';

  const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
       @font-face {
       font-family: 'Amaranth-Bold';
       src: url('${fontUrls1}') format('truetype'); 
       }

       body {
          font-family: 'Amaranth-Bold';
       }

       body.fontLoaded {
          font-family: 'Amaranth-Bold' ;
       }'
```

My app.js file

```
     const openUberMoveLightObserver = new FontFaceObserver('Amaranth- 
      Bold',{});
```

Executing this line throws an error.

```
 openUberMoveLightObserver.load().then(() => {
    document.body.classList.add('fontLoaded');
  });
```

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: did one of the guys below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import fonts to add into styles....
You can do this just passing url to the fonts
like this.....

```
export const MyFonts = createGlobalStyle` 
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'Metropolis';
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-ExtraLight.ttf);
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-Light.ttf);
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-LightItalic.ttf);
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-Medium.ttf);
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.ttf);
  src: url(/static/fonts/Metropolis-SemiBold.ttf);
}
`;
```

**OR**

```
export const MyFonts = createGlobalStyle` 
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-ExtraLight.ttf');
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-Light.ttf');
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-LightItalic.ttf');
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-Medium.ttf');
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.ttf');
  @import url('/static/fonts/Metropolis-SemiBold.ttf');
`;
```

you can use this font by importing inside your component

```
import React from 'react';
import MyFonts from './MyFonts';

function Example(){
    return (
        <div>
            <MyFonts />
            ....
        </div>
    )
}

export default Example
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing

Comment: did you use that font ? like `font-family: Metropolis`

Comment: I have the same issue and the font is not loaded.  The interesting part that one fort is ok, and another one just not there. both are ttf

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specific loader to load the font. For example if you are using webpack then you can use url-loader as below:

```
{
    test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    use: [
      {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          prefix: "font",
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: "application/octet-stream"
        }
      }
    ]   }
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i tried everything at last importing using es5 syntax worked for me

```
let font=require("location to your ttf file like ../src/font/roboto.ttf");
```

and keep your ttf file inside src folder